# My variable take unknown value when trying to use out of the scope of s3.getObject function

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am using s3.getObject function in my nodejs application, and I am unable to use my variables out of the scope of the s3.getObject bloc.

This is the my nodejs Application Controller that I am using to render my data into the view.

```js
// Copyright 2018 IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
//  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
//  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
//  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
//  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
//  limitations under the License.

var galleryController = function(title) {

    var aws = require('ibm-cos-sdk');
    var multer = require('multer');
    var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
    var ep = new aws.Endpoint('');
    var s3 = new aws.S3({endpoint: '});
    var myBucket = '';

    var upload = multer({
        storage: multerS3({
            s3: s3,
            bucket: myBucket,
            key: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, file.originalname);
                console.log(file);
            }
        })
    });

    var getGalleryFile = function (req, res) {

        var imageUrlList = [];
        var file_content = '';
        var params = {Bucket: myBucket};
        var nb_word ;
        var json_result='';
        s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
            if(data != null && data.Contents != null) {

                for (var i = 0; i < data.Contents.length; i++) {
                    var itemKey = data.Contents[i].Key;
                    params = {Bucket:myBucket, Key: itemKey};

                    s3.getObject(params, function (err2, data) {
                        if (!err){
                            file_content = data.Body.toString('utf-8');
                            nb_word = file_content.split(" ").length
                            json_result = JSON.stringify({name:itemKey, count_word:nb_word});
                            //console.log(json_result);
                            console.log(file_content);
                        }
                    });

                    //Create JSON object
                    var urlParams = {Bucket: myBucket, Key: json_result};

                    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', urlParams, function (err, json_result) {
                        imageUrlList[i] = json_result;//JSON.stringify(itemContent);
                    });
                }
            }
            res.render('galleryView', {
                title: title,
                imageUrls: imageUrlList
            });
        });
    };

    return {
        getGalleryFile: getGalleryFile,
        upload: upload
    };
};

module.exports = galleryController;
```

I expected to have the json_result value as ith value (imageUrlList[i] = json_result), but the output value is "unknown". 
But I can see the real value of the json_result while using it in the scope of the s3.getObject function.